# Undefined function 'visboundaries' for input arguments of type 'char'

Tags: matlab

I'm going to use of 'activecontour' command in matlab and I'm using of matlab help of this command. but when I enter this line of codefrom matlab help:
 visboundaries(bw,'Color','r');

It gives me the error as the title of this post.

Could u please guide me?

my matlab version is R2013a.

Thanks

Comment: Are you running the complete example or just a line?

Comment: complete example.    start from   I=imread(toyobjects.png)

Comment: Run this in command window: `whos bw` , what does it give you?

Comment: Name        Size              Bytes  Class      Attributes

  bw        375x380            142500  logical

Comment: Does it readable? its size equal=375x380

Comment: Enter this in command window: `openExample('images/VisualizeSegmentationResultExample')`  , it will open the exact example that you're using. Run it and check if you still receive any error!

Comment: I found the reason of error.   the 'visboundaries' command Introduced in R2015a.   and I'm in R2013a.    Thanks for your responsibility dear Sardar_Usama